# Interpolation of irregularly spaced data into 3d grid

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, 3d, interpolation

I'm working with some instrument data that has records the temperature at a specific latitude, longitude, and pressure (height) coordinate. I need to create a 3d grid from this instrument data that I can then use to take a vertical cross sections of the interpolated gridded data. I've looked at pretty much every interpolation function/library I can find and I'm still having trouble just wrapping my head around how to do this.

I'd prefer not to use Mayavi, since it seems to bug out on my school's server and I'd rather not try to deal with fixing it right now.

The data is currently in 4 separate 1d arrays and I used those to mock up some scatter plots of what I'm trying to get.

Here is the structure of my instrument data points:
[image]

And here is what I'm trying to create:
[image]

Ultimately, I'd like to create some kind of 3d contour from these points that I can take slices of. Each of the plotted points has a corresponding temperature attached to it, which is really what I think is throwing me off in terms of dimensions and whatnot.

Comment: Matplotlib maybe your best bet: http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#scatter-plots

Comment: Maybe I worded it poorly, but I don't need to create a scatter plot.  I was just using that to show the structure of the arrays that I'm trying to create.  I need to interpolate my 3d temperature array into a gridded 3d array over a set region.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few options to go from the unstructured data which you have to a structured dataset.

The simplest option might be to use the scipy [interpolate.griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) method which can interpolate unstructured points using, linear or cubic interpolation.

Another option is to define your grid and then average all of the unstructured points which fall into each grid cell, giving you some gridded representation of the data. You could use a tool such as [CIS](https://github.com/cedadev/cis) to do this easily (full disclosure, I wrote this package to do exactly this kind of thing).

Or, there are more complicated methods of interpolating the data by trying to determine the most likely value of the grid points based on the unstructured data, for example using [kriging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriging) with the [pyKriging](http://www.pykriging.com) package, though I've never used this.